# Singleton design patterns and Differences between different types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton, nsoperationqueue

There are different types of singleton implementation.

First:

```
static MyGlobalClass *instance = nil;
+(MyGlobalClass*)myinstance
{
@synchronized(self)
{
    if(instance==nil)
    {
        instance= [MyGlobalClass new];
   }
}
return instance;
}
```

Second:

```
+(PKShareClass *)sharedInstance
{
static PKShareClass *shaedInstance;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    shaedInstance = [[PKShareClass alloc]init];
});

return shaedInstance;}
```

And finally with

```
static NSOperationQueue * _connectionQueue = nil;
+ (NSOperationQueue *) connectionQueue{
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    if (!_connectionQueue)
    {
        _connectionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    }
});
return _connectionQueue;
}
```

Here my question is what it means when we initialize like first and second ??
And third one with NSOperationQueue. What is the use when we initialize like third one?
Hard to find the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that i can't give you a link which can explain clearly about both 3 way but i will tell you what i understand.

- First way: You create **instance is a static variable of MyGlobalClass class**. In `myinstance` method, you check if `instance` is initialized or not. If not, initialize `instance`. After all, return value of `instance`. Because `instance` is a static variable of MyGlobalClass so when you call `[MyGlobalClass myinstance]`, it's always one object.
- Second way: You create **shaedInstance is a static variable of method sharedInstance**. When you call `dispatch_once(&onceToken`, the code inside block is called only one time. About `dispatch_once`, you can take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once). Because the initialization method is called only one time, `shaedInstance` is always one object when you return it. Actually, there is no different if shaedInstance is a static variable of `PKShareClass` class. You can use both 2 ways.
- Third way: As you can understand after i explain about second way. This way is same like second way when `shaedInstance` is a static variable of `PKShareClass` class. But you don't need to check `!_connectionQueue` inside `dispatch_once`. Because it runs only one time and grossly it's always `nil` at the first time. This way can refactor like:

  ```
  static NSOperationQueue * _connectionQueue = nil;

  + (NSOperationQueue *) connectionQueue{
      static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
      dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
          if (!_connectionQueue)
          _connectionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
      });
      return _connectionQueue;
   }
  ```

Hope my answer can help you understand 3 ways easier ;)

Comment: @ trungduc: Thank you..Can we use all of the above ways in one singleton class ??

Comment: No -.- you need to learn more what is `Singleton` here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. Just use 1 in 3 ways with one class. @UdayEega

Comment: Thank you.@trungduc